# pyspark join left without duplicates

Tags: pyspark

I have left pyspark df:

```
+----------+----------+
|session_id|time      |
+----------+----------+
|1         |10        |
|2         |20        |
|3         |30        |
```

And right:

```
+----------+----------+
|res_id    |sess_id   |
+----------+----------+
|1         |1         |
|2         |2         |  
|1         |1         |
```

I need to receive:

```
+----------+---------+----------+
|res_id    |sess_id  | time     |
+----------+---------+----------+
|1         |1        |  10      |
|2         |2        |  20      |
|1         |1        |  10      |
```

How to achieve it ? left / inner joins are duplicating my res_id records....

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> left / inner joins are duplicating my res_id records....

Perhaps if you shared your code it would help?

This seems to do what you need:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

left = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        {"session_id": 1, "time": 10},
        {"session_id": 2, "time": 20},
        {"session_id": 3, "time": 30},
    ]
)

right = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        {"res_id": 1, "sess_id": 1},
        {"res_id": 2, "sess_id": 2},
        {"res_id": 3, "sess_id": 1},
    ]
)

(
    left.join(right, left.session_id == right.sess_id).select(
        "res_id", "sess_id", "time"
    )
).show()
```

which outputs:

```bash
+------+-------+----+                                                           
|res_id|sess_id|time|  
+------+-------+----+  
|     1|      1|  10|  
|     3|      1|  10|  
|     2|      2|  20|  
+------+-------+----+
```

which is the same as your desired output above.

Comment: Sorry, it was incorrect dataset on my side, indeed you are correct !